# Spring Integration Aggregator and SimpleMessageGroup memory leak

Tags: out-of-memory, spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration application and are getting out of memory errors during high throughput (a production batch process). The application is utilizing Spring-integration-core release 4.3.10. We are using org.springframework.integration.annotation* in our application and on our Aggregator object (@MessageEndpoint/@Autowired/@Aggregator) and have a custom a 'aggregate' method.

In heap dumps, I am seeing SimpleMessageGroup (and other associated objects) from high throughput runs and also when individual SoapUI requests are run. Please see the attached screen shots.

I have read there are a number of variables that can be set in the 'AggregatingMessageHandler' object. In order to gain access to these variables, while still utilizing 'spring.integration.annotation' and with a custom 'aggregate' method', I changed my annotated Aggregator object extend 'AggregatingMessageHandler'.

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MyAggregator extends AggregatingMessageHandler {

    private final MyLogger myTransactionLogger;

   @Autowired
   public CIPAggregator( MyLogger myTransactionLogger) {
       super(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(), new SimpleMessageStore());
      this.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(false);
      this.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
      //this.setMinimumTimeoutForEmptyGroups(500);
      this.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(1000L));
      this.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
      this.cipTransactionLogger = cipTransactionLogger;

    }
  @Aggregator(inputChannel = "serviceResponseChannel", outputChannel="aggregatorResponseChannel")
    public <T> IndividualInquiryResponse aggregate(List<Message> serviceResponses) {...custom code }
```

I have tried different settings and combinations of the above variables, but I continue to see the same behavior.

[image: SoapUI request details of SimpleMessageGroup Instance One]
[image: SoapUI request details of SimpleMessageGroup Instance Two]
[image: Screen shot of High Throughput run]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Update June 6, 2018
Per instruction from Artem Bilan 
Successfully configured Aggregator by utilizing @Bean\@ServiceActivator annotation with AggregatorFactoryBean. (MyAggregator object does not contain any annotations)

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceResponseChannel")
FactoryBean<MessageHandler> aggregatorFactoryBean( ) {
    AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setProcessorBean(new MyAggregator(myTransactionLogger()));
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setMethodName("aggregate");
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setMessageStore(new SimpleMessageStore());
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setOutputChannel(aggregatorResponseChannel());
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(1900L));// @MessagingGateway defaultReplyTimeout=2000
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(false);

    aggregatorFactoryBean.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);

    return aggregatorFactoryBean;
}
```

Receiving responses as expected, but still have memory leak issues with SimpleMessageGroup and associated objects. One SimpleMessageGroup per request.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using a custom aggregate method within an Aggregator object, define an AggregatorFactoryBean similar to the following. Your Aggregator object should not contain an annotations

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceResponseChannel")
FactoryBean<MessageHandler> aggregatorFactoryBean( ) {
    AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setProcessorBean(new MyAggregator(myTransactionLogger()));//your Aggregator object
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setMethodName("aggregate");//your aggregator method
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setMessageStore(new SimpleMessageStore());
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setOutputChannel(aggregatorResponseChannel());
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(false);    
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);    
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
    aggregatorFactoryBean.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(1900L));// @MessagingGateway defaultReplyTimeout=2000
    return aggregatorFactoryBean;
}

public class MyAggregator {
    private final MyLogger myTransactionLogger;
    public MyAggregator( MyLogger myTransactionLogger) {
       this.myTransactionLogger = myTransactionLogger;
    }
    public <T> InquiryResponse aggregate(List<Message> serviceResponses) {
       your aggregatation code.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, share with us what is the `ReleaseStrategy` for your use-case.

By default an aggregator tries to group messages by the `correlationId` header.
And decides when it is time to release group by the `sequenceSize` header. If this condition isn't met, the group is not released and remains in the memory.

Consider to use `@ServiceActivator` instead on the `AggregatorFactoryBean` `@Bean` though.

Comment: Hi Artem, We are using the default ReleaseStrategy and we are receiving the expected responses from our requests, that said, do I need to create a custom Release Strategy? - thank you

Comment: I'm afraid your `MyAggregator extends AggregatingMessageHandler` trick doesn't and a default aggregator is created from that `@Aggregator` annotation. Consider what I suggested you via an `AggregatorFactoryBean`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to

Comment: I already tried the example in documentation that returns a MessageHandler:

Comment: Yeah... The same sample, but with the `AggregatorFactoryBean` for more fine-grained configuration

Comment: ahh, ok thank you.  And that should allow me to reach a custom aggregate method? I will give it a try

Comment: Hi Artem - I am not seeing where I can configure the use of a custom aggregate method when implementing @Bean\@ServiceActivator annotation to return an AggregatorFactoryBean, which you suggested as a replacement to using @Aggregator annotation, so that all of the AggregatingMessageHandler attributes are available. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Not sure what you are missing, but there is this to configure `setProcessorBean()` and your `@Aggregator` will be scanned by the `MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor` internally.

Comment: Hi Artem - Thank you for your help with configuring the AggregatorFactoryBean. The application is up and running and I have access to the all of the attributes contained in the MessageHandler. I configured the attributes as shown above  (from xml configdocumentation example ) and I am still having memory leak issues.  I am not using a reaper and I am not using a task scheduler , I am using a taskExecutor with these settings (core.pool.size=10, max.pool.size=20, queue.capacity=100, allow.core.thread.timeout=true, keep.alive.seconds=120) - your time and assistance is appreciated

Comment: Wait. What is this `aggregatorFactoryBean.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(false);`? It must be `true` if you are going to clean up completed groups from the memory.

Comment: Thanks! It was a thing of beauty to see those numbers staying down :-)

Comment: But before I am finished, a couple more questions about the attributes: Is it reasonable to set aggregatorFactoryBean.setGroupTimeoutExpression and aggregatorFactoryBean.setMinimumTimeoutForEmptyGroups both to 2000 to match the defaultReplyTimeout value that is set in our@MessagingGateway annotation? And to double check, both setExpireGroupsUponTimeout and setExpireGroupsUponCompletion should be set to true. I will update the aggregatorFactoryBean defined above, so hopefully we will have helped others going forward. thanks again

Comment: Well, yes, you can set a `GroupTimeoutExpression` slightly less, than `defaultReplyTimeout` on the Gateway to really try to get a reply from such a sub-flow to the gateway request. The `MinimumTimeoutForEmptyGroups` won't help here because it will just clean empty groups without any replies. Right, `ExpireGroupsUponTimeout` has the same reason as `GroupTimeoutExpression`.

Comment: Great! May we accept the answer now to help other people here to determine that we have a solution?